What is the movie where the girl talks the robber into giving the money out on the bus
There was an english movie where there is a girl and a guy on a bus or train. A robber comes up and tries to rob them, the guy is scared i believe, but the girl is really nice and asks him what he needs money for and after a second talks him into handing out her money to anyone who needs it and gives her the rest back. I think it is a late 90s or early 2000 movie.

This happened in the 2006 movie "Ira & Abby".  From Wikipedia:

Desperate to enjoy each other, the two take the subway from a bad neighborhood. They are mugged at gunpoint on the way, and Abby steps up to face the mugger and offer him the money he needs. Ira is scared at first, and then proud of his new wife.

If this is the movie you're thinking of, be sure to close this question by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. Thanks!
